# Correct way of returning an error code in a method

Tags: java

I have this method in a "Point" class:

```
public Point sumPoints(Point p) {
        if(dimension != p.getDimension())
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrong dimensions.");

        Double[] coord = new Double[dimension];
        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
            coord[i] = coordinates[i] + p.getCoord(i);
        Point P = new Point(coord);

        return P;
```

The idea is that points can be n-dimensional, so I should check that the dimensions of the points match before trying to add them up. The thing is that in the case that they don't match, I can't return a specific value (`-1` for example, as I did in C), because the return type is `Point`.

What should I do in these cases? Is the RuntimeExeption an okay practice?

Comment: Throwing an exception is fine, but `IllegalArgumentException` (a subtype of `RuntimeException`) is more meaningful.

Comment: It all depends on your flavor. Throwing exceptions is expensive, but they're not discouraged if used in the right moments. I think you're okay with throwing it here. But you also could just return `null` and do something with that value.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is a much more elegant way to implement error handling in Java for a number of reasons.

### Error codes

Returning error codes [works well in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/386001/1391325) especially because of the ability to pass pointers as function parameters in C: In this way, you can e.g. create a new object inside the function and "return" it via the pointer passed to the function and let the function actually `return` a proper error code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int create_message_str(char *p_message, const size_t p_message_len)
{
    int result = -1;

    const char message[] = "Hello, world!";
    if (NULL != p_message && strlen(message) <= p_message_len)
    {
        strcpy(p_message, message);
        result = 0;     
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    const size_t p_message_len = 13;
    char *p_message = malloc(p_message_len * sizeof(char));

    if (create_message_str(p_message, p_message_len) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p_message);
        result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } 
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Could not copy string to pointer memory.");
    }

    free(p_message);

    return result;
}
```

In Java, however, you'd have to create an instance of e.g. some sort of mutable [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)-like object for holding the reference to the object which would be referenced by the pointer in the C function:

```
public class ReferenceSwapper {

    private static class MutableSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {

        private T supplied;

        public MutableSupplier(final T supplied) {
            this.supplied = supplied;
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            return supplied;
        }

        public void set(final T supplied) {
            this.supplied = supplied;
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final MutableSupplier<String> firstSupplier = new MutableSupplier<String>("foo");
        final MutableSupplier<String> secondSupplier = new MutableSupplier<String>("bar");
        System.out.println("Before reference swap: " + firstSupplier.get() + secondSupplier.get());
        swapSupplied(firstSupplier, secondSupplier);
        System.out.println("After reference swap: " + firstSupplier.get() + secondSupplier.get());
    }

    private static <T> void swapSupplied(final MutableSupplier<T> firstSupplier,
            final MutableSupplier<T> secondSupplier) {
        final T firstSupplied = firstSupplier.get();
        final T secondSupplied = secondSupplier.get();
        firstSupplier.set(secondSupplied);
        secondSupplier.set(firstSupplied);
    }
}
```

This code prints out:

```
Before reference swap: foobar
After reference swap: barfoo
```

As you can see, this is ridiculously complicated in Java due to its [pass-by-value semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1391325).

### Exceptions

However, Java offers a much higher-level way of defining error-handling behavior: Exceptions. Although [some people debate if the idea of exceptions are a good thing or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1736146/1391325) and [exception handling is really just fancy conditional logic](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~aycock/papers/plc05.pdf), they are part of the Java language and [can work well](http://jonskeet.uk/java/passing.html#workaround) for reporting exceptional (i.e. erroneous) states.

As [Andy Turner already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36559469/1391325#comment-60719460), throwing an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) would be the most natural way of reporting an error regarding the method's particular arguments which you shouldn't (normally) have to catch and handle: You'd be assuming that the people using `sumPoints(Point p)` are smart enough to pass the correct arguments or at least to suffer a program halt if they aren't so. However, if you *do* expect that this is a common occurrence is at least an occurrence which cannot be avoided purely through judicious programming (e.g. if the data is read from disk and might somehow get corrupted or not be available), then it might be better to throw a caught exception in order to force the calling method to handle the case where this happens.

Answer (score 0):

In short the answer to your question is yes. Exceptions is the accepted way to handle errors. There are a lot of Exceptions that are more specific that inherit from `RuntimeException` though.[IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) comes to mind. Also you can write your own exceptions that inherit from a `RuntimeException`. And then of course there is a mammoth of a discussion about which Exception to use Unchecked (inheriting from `RuntimeException`) or checked (inheriting from `Exception`). Just type in Google "runtimeexception vs exception" and you will get a screenfull of links to keep you buisy :). Here is just one Example: [difference between java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190161/difference-between-java-lang-runtimeexception-and-java-lang-exception). There is no clear cut answer for that. You will have to choose on your own.

Answer (score -1):

the thing with exceptions in java is that you can code your own class that extends from Exception to use it in a class which you treat all kind of possible exceptions that could encounter your program then you just throw it.
example :

```
public class Erreur extends Exception{
String message; 
public Erreur(String message){
this.message=message;    
}    
public String getMessage(){ return message;}
}
```

Then

```
public class Calcule {
    public static double division(double x, double y) throws Erreur{
    double r=0;
    Erreur erre=new Erreur("can't divide by zero");
    if(y==0) throw (erre); 
    else r=(x/y);
    return r;
             } 
   }
```

Comment: While there might be cases where it's useful to have all the exception types specific to a program inherit from a common class, doing so simply for ease of catching them is an abuse of the exception-handling mechanism: `Erreur` can represent wildly different problems and so a person trying to use your code would have a Hell of a time figuring out how to deal with each individual case.

Comment: totally agree,  what i wrote is juste in case when someone is trying to treat some special exceptions.